# Enable/disable tcp PSH Flag from user space

Tags: networking, tcp, linux-kernel, ip

Is there any way to set/reset TCP PSH Flag option from User space process ?

I don't find any socket option to alter this flag option
Please input your suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

No. The PSH flag has never made the slightest difference to the operation of any TCP API I have ever encountered in nearly 25 years. It it a basically redundant part of the original TCP specification. There is nothing to be gained by setting it or not setting it, even if there was a way to do so, which there isn't.